# How to display all the data of a CSV file in a HTML page?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a code in django that reads a csv file and stores its data in a database, what I intend to do is show that data in an HTML page, this is my view:

```
def addbulkuser(request):                                                                                  
prompt = {                                                                                             
    'order': 'Order of the file should be: Username, First name, Last name, Email & Password'          
}                                                                                                      

if request.method == "GET":                                                                            
    return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html', prompt)                                        

data_file = request.FILES['file']                                                                      

if not data_file.name.endswith('.csv'):                                                                
    messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')                                                  

if data_file.name.endswith('.csv'):                                                                    
    data_set = data_file.read().decode('UTF-8')                                                        
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)                                                                  
    next(io_string)                                                                                    
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):                                 
        created = User.objects.update_or_create(                                                       
            username=column[0],                                                                        
            first_name=column[1],                                                                      
            last_name=column[2],                                                                       
            email=column[3],                                                                           
            password=column[4],                                                                        
            last_login=datetime.now(),                                                                 
        )                                                                                              

        user = User.objects.get(username=column[0])                                                    
        user.set_password(user.password)                                                               
        user.save()                                                                                    
        andon_user_group = Group.objects.get(name='andon_user')                                        
        andon_user_group.user_set.add(user)                                                            
    col = column                                                                                       
    colu = messages.success(request, 'Users added successfully')                                       
    context = {'col': col,                                                                             
               'colu': colu                                                                            
               }                                                                                       
    return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html', context)                                       

return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html')
```

The variable **"col"** contains all the data in the csv file and I have it called this way in the HTML:

```
{% for column in col %}
        {{ column }}
    {% endfor %}
```

But it only shows me in the html the last data in the CSV file, how could I show all the data?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently only saves that last data in the CSV file to the variable `col` and hence that's the only data passed in the context.

If you want to display all the data, you may be considering creating a list of lists, where each list will contain the data of an individual.

For example, this is one of the methods that you can incorporate into your program.

```py
listoflists = []
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    sublist = []
    for j in range(0,6)
        sublist.append(column[j])
    listoflists.append(sublist)

context = {'col': listoflists,                                                                             
            'colu': colu                                                                            
          }                                                                                       
return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html', context)
```

In the template you may access it like

```
{% for values in col %}
  {% for value in values %}
    The value is {{value}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```